# Through jdbc template multiple column value are coming how can i store it in a map in java

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

Through jdbc template multiple column values are returned by my query. How can i store it in a map in Java?

Suppose I have a query like this:

```
SELECT Employee_Name, Employee_Age 
FROM Employee 
WHERE Employee_ID=1
```

in result of this query we got like **Employee Name and Employee_Age as respect to Employee_ID**. How to store this value in a map where key is name and age, value is what we get from database.

Comment: can you please paste your code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this solution in java8 will help:

```
jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT Employee_Name, Employee_Age FROM Employee WHERE Employee_ID=1", (ResultSet rs) -> {
    HashMap<String,String> results = new HashMap<>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        results.put(rs.getString("Employee_Name"), rs.getString("Employee_Age"));
    }
    return results;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For key, we can merge Employee_Name and Employee_Age separated by '-' like:

> rs.getString("Employee_Name")+"-"+rs.getString("Employee_Age")

For value, the whole object should be put as you said: **what we get from the database.**

> rs.getObject(i)

```
jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT Employee_Name, Employee_Age FROM Employee WHERE Employee_ID=1", (ResultSet rs) -> {
HashMap<String,String> results = new HashMap<>();
int i = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
    results.put(rs.getString("Employee_Name")+"-"+rs.getString("Employee_Age"), rs.getObject(i));
    i++;
}
return results;
});
```